# ASP.NET Core Web API - Entity Framework One to Many not giving the expected result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am implementing one to many ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using Entity Framework.

I have these three model classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Merchant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MerchantUser> MerchantUsers { get; set; }
}

public class MerchantUser
{
    public Guid MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
}
```

This is my repository:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<MerchantUser>> GetMerchantUserAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    var merchantUsers = _dbContext.MerchantUsers
                                  .Include(x => x.Merchant.User)
                                  .Include(x => x.Merchant)
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
    return merchantUsers;
}
```

`ApplicationUser` is from ASP.NET Core Identity.

All the users have their details in `ApplicationUser`. The `ApplicationUser` is not for `Merchant` only. A merchant will have many `MerchantUsers`, but a `MerchantUser` will belong to only one `Merchant`.

So far, this is what I have on POSTMAN:

```
"pageItems": [
    {
        "id": "97ea4e97-3933-4a1e-a573-e149e1abdf84",
        "merchantId": "67a21699-dfe6-4cb6-96b6-e009fd389596",
        "userId": "1ec3c912-cf78-4d0a-a243-3d626b85c3cf",
        "merchant": {
            "id": "67a21699-dfe6-4cb6-96b6-e009fd389596",
            "merchantName": "Merchant Ltd Limited",
            "accountNumber": "1234567890"
    }
  }
]
```

It's not displaying the users that belong to each `Merchant`.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try  .Include(x => x.User) instead of .Include(x => x.Merchant.User) ?

Comment: I don't find any property named `User` in your  `Merchant` entity,  `Include(x => x.Merchant.User)` will not report any error in your project?